# Join two tables by MRN and date1 >= MAX(date2)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to combine the data from two hospital activity reports. What happens is this: Patients get admitted to a spinal department. Some of whom then get referred to put on ventilation. After a while patient is discharged. Later, the same patient may or may not get re-referred back to the spinal department and may or may not be re-referred for ventilation. I am sent activity data in two reports:

Monthly Activity Report:

```
[MRN] [NHS Number] [Admission Date] [DoB] [Blah] [Blah]
```

Ventilation Report

```
[MRN] [Admission Date]  [Ventilation Days]   [Ventilation Type] [blah] [blah]
```

N.B. The Admission Date on the Ventilation Report is the date they are referred for ventilation. This may be the same day, or some date after they are referred into spinal dept.

What I need to achieve is this: join each row to the most immediate entry prior to the patient being referred to ventilation. I need to avoid duplicating rows, but I cannot join it to the most recent row in the Monthly Activity Report as this could easily be a subsequent referral and the other information will not be applicable.

By following the answer to a similar question on Stackoverflow, I came up with this code:

```
SELECT [Year], [Month], MRN, [NHS Number], [Admission Date] AS [VD 
Admission Date], 
[Admit date] AS [MAR Admit Date], Days,
[Ventilation Type], [Ventilation Route], [Ventilation Time], [Package of 
care class],
[Para/Tetra/No deficit], [Social charge date commenced ] AS [Social charge 
date], [Discharge date]
FROM Spinal_Costing.Vented_Days VD
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Patient MRN] ORDER BY 
[Admit Date] DESC) AS row
    FROM Spinal_Costing.MAR
 ) MAR ON VD.MRN = MAR.[Patient MRN]
 WHERE MAR.row = 1;
```

But this returns the most recent entry in MAR for each patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also be achieved with an `apply` that references the values in `Vented_Days` and simply returns a `top 1` for each row.  `cross apply` won't return `null` values whereas `outer apply` will:

```
declare @vd table(MRN int,AdmissionDate date);
declare @mar table(MRN int,AdmissionDate date);

insert into @vd values
 (1,'20190102')
,(1,'20190106')
,(2,'20190104')
,(3,'20190101');

insert into @mar values
 (1,'20190101')
,(1,'20190105')
,(2,'20190102');

select v.MRN
        ,v.AdmissionDate
        ,m.AdmissionDate
from @vd as v
    outer apply (select top 1 m.AdmissionDate
                 from @mar as m
                 where v.MRN = m.MRN
                    and v.AdmissionDate >= m.AdmissionDate
                 order by m.AdmissionDate desc
                ) as m
order by v.MRN
        ,v.AdmissionDate;
```

## Output

```
+-----+---------------+---------------+
| MRN | AdmissionDate | AdmissionDate |
+-----+---------------+---------------+
|   1 | 2019-01-02    | 2019-01-01    |
|   1 | 2019-01-06    | 2019-01-05    |
|   2 | 2019-01-04    | 2019-01-02    |
|   3 | 2019-01-01    | NULL          |
+-----+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thank you. Using the Outer Apply join is a technique that I don't use very often, so probably overlook it. The advantage here is that it returns rows will null values where either there is no entry in MAR, or the date is after the admission date in the Vented_Days table. Need to check with the department how to handle that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, you just need to add a `JOIN` to that derived table to limit the rows in the `Spinal_Costing.MAR` table to those that came at, or before discharge.

```
SELECT 
    [Year], 
    [Month], 
    MRN, 
    [NHS Number], 
    [Admission Date] AS [VD Admission Date], 
    [Admit date] AS [MAR Admit Date], 
    Days,
    [Ventilation Type], 
    [Ventilation Route], 
    [Ventilation Time], 
    [Package of care class],
    [Para/Tetra/No deficit], 
    [Social charge date commenced ] AS [Social charge date], 
    [Discharge date]
FROM 
    Spinal_Costing.Vented_Days VD
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Patient MRN] ORDER BY [Admit Date] DESC) AS row
    FROM Spinal_Costing.MAR 
    --added the JOIN and WHERE clause here
    INNER JOIN Spinal_Costing.Vented_Days 
        ON Spinal_Costing.Vented_Days.MRN = Spinal_Costing.MAR.[Patient MRN]
    WHERE  Spinal_Costing.MAR.[Admit Date]  <= Spinal_Costing.Vented_Days.[Discharge date]
 ) MAR ON VD.MRN = MAR.[Patient MRN]
 WHERE MAR.row = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, so close! I was staring at this one for ages yesterday. As mentioned in my comment above, what I have now noticed is that there are entries in the Vented_Days table that have no corresponding entry in MAR where the date is equal or prior. What this option above does is exclude those entries. Need to check with the department what the desired outcome is.

Comment: @Paul_G seems like time to open another question. Also you can't accept two answers (i saw you flipping them back and forth) but when you have enough reputation (15) you can upvote helpful answers.

Comment: Thanks @Scsimon, it appears my question(s) have been answered now. Both answers were perfectly workable and yours was closer to the original code that I had created. It was simply resolved by adding an extra join to the derived table. However I have decided to use the solution devised by iamdave as it returns all the rows with nulls where a join is missing between the two tables as well as the coding being more succinct.

Comment: If you change the INNER JOIN to a LEDT JOIN you’d get the same results too

Comment: Yes, that's true.